# Помогите распарсить JSON-ответ в php

Tags: php, json, парсер, json-encode

Помогите пожалуйста распарсить в PHP:

```
{
  "id": "0",
  "jsonrpc": "2.0",
  "result": {
    "balance": 0,
    "blocks_to_unlock": 0,
    "multisig_import_needed": false,
    "per_subaddress": [{
      "account_index": 0,
      "address": "48kR7XQ2pJ518LycQjkQbHRbc7s15UoJsQ3KyLbK9iwXghC8RZp1k9j54sgKp5XtU9dxvwVPSpK3zJTRSYVGajgmRxrsRzT",
      "address_index": 0,
      "balance": 0,
      "blocks_to_unlock": 0,
      "label": "Primary account",
      "num_unspent_outputs": 1,
      "time_to_unlock": 0,
      "unlocked_balance": 0
    },{
      "account_index": 0,
      "address": "88cZAYhZQJPSKDcrqprTyc6EJujz72uoX7uLUrZH9CHgiMS5nKO1n2sNEvcGkHK2Y3K16dy2NwqHXcBEgyVs3M1b9NFHmCN",
      "address_index": 1,
      "balance": 0,
      "blocks_to_unlock": 0,
      "label": "",
      "num_unspent_outputs": 0,
      "time_to_unlock": 0,
      "unlocked_balance": 0
    }],
    "time_to_unlock": 0,
    "unlocked_balance": 0
  }
}
```

Мне нужно получить вот эту строку:

**"address": "88cZAYhZQJPSKDcrqprTyc6EJujz72uoX7uLUrZH9CHgiMS5nKO1n2sNEvcGkHK2Y3K16dy2NwqHXcBEgyVs3M1b9NFHmCN",**

`$response['result']['per_subaddress'][0]['address']`
Вот таким способом захватывается первый адрес, а мне нужен второй. Как его захватить?

Comment: Это такой пранк что ли?

Comment: Знаете о том, что у массивов есть численные индексы?

Comment: И тебе спасибо умник, что навёл на правильный путь и минусанул мой вопрос)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$response['result']['per_subaddress'][1]['address']

Comment: Спасибо добрый человек!